# Reference of "keystore.jks" file in the project path

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter

I saw that someone put the keystore.jks file in their "app" reference project folder. I think this can be dangerous ... if it isn't, why?

Comment: it is dangerous, don't do it - maybe let the person who you saw do it know

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR : DANGEROUS**

> JKS contains private keys, which must be protected because they are
>   used to decrypt information encrypted by public keys.

Making the JKS easily available to lets say hackers, will make it one step easier to decrypt your app data.

**It is very possible for someone to build a release apk using the exposed JKS and get access to deployment level APIs as used by Firebase, Facebook etc.**

There are [some ways to recover or change the Keystore password](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/forgot-keystore-passwordjks-file-you-can-still-recover-it) and this clearly shows why it is crazy to expose the JKS.

For example, someone who got hands on your JKS and is somehow able to get the keystore password, key alias and key password, they can build the release apk and modify the code to mess with your backend or API calls.

Comment: It is crazy, true. Because I've seen some suggest this on Github

Comment: Woah, please send me that link. I'd like to know their POV xD

Comment: Haha I would love to, but I'd feel someone's sensitivity. The answer was given to me